# Read variable from JSON file on remote host and use it as condition for the task in ansible playbook

Tags: json, variables, ansible

I have bunch of JSON files on hostA. I am running playbook on my dev server. My goal is to read variable from JSON files on hostA, and use the varible as condition in my playbook to perform other tasks. I can read JSON file on my dev server using include_vars and use the variable as condition to perform task. However, I am having trouble to read JSON file on hostA. Looks like include_vars only works for localhost. Is there any other module I can use to achieve my goal? My playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: hostA
  tasks:      
    - include_vars: 
         file: /mypath/myfile.json
         name: my_var

    - name: Create file if var_a in json file is less than 5
      file:
         path: /mypath/myfile
         state: touch
      when: '"{{ my_var.var_a|int }}" < 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

[fetch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fetch_module.html) the file and use it in *include_vars*.

Answer (score 0):

The approach using fetch and include_vars will not work for more than one machine at a time, as you will not be able to separate facts per machine.

Instead you could consider using facts to achieve your goal. Below I have created a script in /etc/ansible/facts.d on the remote machine (hostA for example), and made it executable for everyone:

```
$ cd /etc/ansible/facts.d
$ chmod 0755 example.fact
$ cat example.fact

#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
kv = {'mykey': 'myvalue'}
print json.dumps(kv)
```

when I run it, it produces json

```
$ ./example.fact
{"mykey": "myvalue"}
```

Add this to your role or playbook - it will run all scripts in /etc/ansible/facts.d

```
- name: read local facts
  setup:
    filter: ansible_local
```

And verify you got what you wanted

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: ansible_local.example
```

Ansible output:

```
ok: [hostA] => {
    "ansible_local.example": {
        "mykey": "myvalue"
    }
}
```

If you want to read custom values from your remote machine into your playbook execution, all you need now is to modify the example.fact script to consume the info and produce it as json, e.g:

```
with open('/tmp/info.json') as json_file:
    myinfo = json.load(json_file)

print json.dumps(myinfo)
```